# Error when using dependency com.vladmihalcea in a test in a web page project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

Im trying to run a test in my web page application project.

But I'm getting an error related to this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

I need this dependency because I'm using arrays in my Postgres db while using hibernate and had trouble handling these arrays until I included this dependency. My web page application works fine but for some reason when I try to run a test in my persistance layer I get the following error messages:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence.config.TestConfig
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType]
```

I think this has to do with the fact that in my `WebConfig` I'm using the following dialect:

- `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect`

But in my `TestConfig` I have to use `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` and this dependency works with the `PostgreSQL92Dialect` but has conflicts with the `HSQLDialect`.

My test:

```
@Rollback
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class PostDaoImplTest {
    private static final String EMAIL = "mail@test.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String NAME = "Juan";
    private static final String LASTNAME = "Perez";

    @Autowired
    private UserJpaDaoImpl userDao;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testCreate() {
        final User user = userDao.register(EMAIL, PASSWORD, NAME, LASTNAME, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
        assertNotNull(user);
    }

}
```

TestConfig:

```
@ComponentScan({"ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence", })
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Value("classpath:schema.sql")
    private Resource schemaSql;

    @Value("classpath:hsqldb.sql")
    private Resource hsqldbSql;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClass(JDBCDriver.class);
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:paw");
        ds.setUsername("");
        ds.setPassword("");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource ds) {
        final DataSourceInitializer dsi = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dsi.setDataSource(ds);
        dsi.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
        return dsi;
    }

    private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        final ResourceDatabasePopulator dbp = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        dbp.addScript(hsqldbSql);
        dbp.addScript(schemaSql);
        return dbp;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityFactory.setPackagesToScan("ar.edu.itba.paw.model");
        entityFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        final JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        final Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update"); //Mejor intento para actualizar el esquema.
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("format_sql", "true");
        entityFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return entityFactory;
    }
}
```

WebConfig:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"ar.edu.itba.paw.webapp.controller", "ar.edu.itba.paw.service", "ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence"})
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("classpath:schema.sql")
    private Resource schemaSql;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClass(org.postgresql.Driver.class);
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql:paw");
        ds.setUsername("postgres");
        ds.setPassword("postgres");
        return ds;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource(){
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ms = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        ms.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        ms.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
        ms.setCacheSeconds(5);

        return ms;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        resolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000000);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityFactory.setPackagesToScan("ar.edu.itba.paw.model");
        entityFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        final JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        final Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update"); 
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect");
        entityFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return entityFactory;
    }
}
```

pom.xml(persistence) dependencies

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>ar.edu.itba.paw</groupId>
      <artifactId>interfaces</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

pom.xml (paw2021a) dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hsqldb.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.validator}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.validation-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-ext-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-ext-spring.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.fileupload.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.codec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: try type-52 or type-parent instead of type-5